# Full Width Main Post

Tags: posts, categories

On my site I want to add a section just below Navigation and above-content (from where posts starts to show up on front page) which would show a panel where I can put any BREAKING NEWS (not always, whenever I want) with its excerpt and image. That panel should stretch with max-width.

I want to pull that BREAKING NEWS from a specific category say - category_breaking.

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Thanks for the help.

I want to achieve exactly like this - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jYuh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, and is a common thing to do with WordPress:

```
<?php
  $q = new WP_Query('category_name=category_breaking'); // query that gets all posts in category "category_breaking"
  if( $q->have_posts() ) : // if there are posts returned by query...
    echo "<div id='breaking_news'>"; // start the breaking news section
    while( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); // start looping through query results
      echo "<div class='bn_post'>"; // single breaking news post start
      echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>"; // display breaking news post title
      if(has_post_thumbnail()) // if post has featured image set...
      {
        the_post_thumbnail(); // then display featured image
      }
      echo "</div>"; // close single breaking news post
    endwhile;
    echo "</div>"; // close breaking news section
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Well, you made it sound so simple. I would be applying that asap and would let you know. :)

Comment: well, after using your help and forking it a bit with the help of various forums. I came to wrap it up with what I need. Thanks. This is the final code I used, which is working fine. http://dpaste.com/hold/790904/